# Change colour of text body in Awesome-CV

Tags: fonts

I use [Awesome-CV template](https://github.com/posquit0/Awesome-CV). It looks great but I find the colour of some portion of text too bright. I mean the text e.g. "Current Co-founder & Software Engineer.." (and many others) in [Résumé](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/posquit0/Awesome-CV/master/examples/resume.pdf) and e.g. text "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, co" of Cover Letter.  I tried to change the colour by trial and error (see below), but without luck.

```
\definecolor{white}{HTML}{000000}
\definecolor{black}{HTML}{000000}
\definecolor{darkgray}{HTML}{000000}
\definecolor{gray}{HTML}{000000}
\definecolor{lightgray}{HTML}{000000}
% Basic colors
\definecolor{green}{HTML}{000000}
\definecolor{orange}{HTML}{000000}
\definecolor{purple}{HTML}{000000}
\definecolor{red}{HTML}{000000}
\definecolor{blue}{HTML}{000000}
% Text colors
\definecolor{darktext}{HTML}{000000}
\colorlet{text}{000000}
\colorlet{graytext}{000000}
\colorlet{lighttext}{000000}
```

**UPDATE**

I've found a workaround. In `awesome-cv.cls` I replaced `\newcommand*{\bodyfontlight}{\sourcesansprolight}` with `\newcommand*{\bodyfontlight}{\sourcesanspro}` but it doesn't change everything.

Comment: What about the important ones (`\definecolor{awesome-emerald}{HTML}{00A388}
\definecolor{awesome-skyblue}{HTML}{0395DE}
\definecolor{awesome-red}{HTML}{DC3522}
\definecolor{awesome-pink}{HTML}{EF4089}
\definecolor{awesome-orange}{HTML}{FF6138}
\definecolor{awesome-nephritis}{HTML}{27AE60}
\definecolor{awesome-concrete}{HTML}{95A5A6}
\definecolor{awesome-darknight}{HTML}{131A28}
\colorlet{awesome}{awesome-red}`)?

Comment: I checked them as well. No luck. I think they are responsible for other colours: some of text starts with red and this colour is to be customised by changing `awesome-red` to  e.g. skyblue, pink etc.

Answer (score 1):

You could add the commands:

```
\definecolor{graytext}{HTML}{00FF00}
\definecolor{gray}{HTML}{0000FF}
```

This will change the text body's, letter opening's and letter closing's colour in the coverletter. It will change the "entrypositionstyle" and "entrydatestyle" in the CV, too.

The other way is to redefine certain commands like that:

```
\renewcommand*{\entrypositionstyle}[1]{{\fontsize{8pt}{1em}\bodyfont\scshape\color{blue} #1}}
```

(Just add this line in cv.tex)

You can look up the command's names to redefine here:
https://github.com/posquit0/Awesome-CV/blob/master/awesome-cv.cls

It is important to redefine them with `\renewcommand` and not `\newcommand`, because it will throw an error otherwise.